# Issue installing RVM for RoR in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm

I'm trying to get Ruby on Rails setup on my new eeeubuntu install and I think I'm having some issues installing RVM properly.

I installed GIT, and that went well. I installed RVM and in the install it told me to add

```
if [[ -s /home/derek/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /home/derek/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
```

To the end of .bashrc
Which I did.

It then said if I have a return in .bashrc it would cause errors. So it said move everything below

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

To .bash_profile
Which I did. When I try and run "rvm install 1.9.1" I get this

```
No command 'rvm' found, but there are 20 similar ones
rvm: command not found
```

So what have I done wrong?

Here are the contents of my .bashrc and .bash_profile

.bashrc

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

.bash_profile

```
# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# don't overwrite GNU Midnight Commander's setting of `ignorespace'.
HISTCONTROL=$HISTCONTROL${HISTCONTROL+,}ignoredups
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
 # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
 # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
 # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
color_prompt=yes
    else
 color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;    34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
#alias ll='ls -l'
#alias la='ls -A'
#alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi

if [[ -s /home/derek/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /home/derek/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need not to move but to remove the `return`.

You also need to add some code to `.bashrc`. You added it to `.bash_profile` but not to `.bashrc`. The line you need to append is

```
if [[ -s /home/derek/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /home/derek/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
```

Please read the instructions from the installer carefully again! I am not sure if there were other things you needed to add.

Comment: Thanks that did it.  I didn't need to add anything else, it was just removing the return that made it work.

Answer (score 5):

I added to .bashrc `export PATH=~/.rvm/bin:$PATH` and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu i did

```
echo 'source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

So my .bashrc looks like this

```
tail -n 5  $HOME/.bashrc


PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```